# Systemd, start user level unit with sudo access

Tags: 16.04, sudo, systemd, dbus

I have a Debian package which installs my software and it needs to start two applications in post install script. First one is daemon and the second one is a background process both are managed with `systemd`. The problem is that I run `sudo dpkg -i ...` , and it fails to start user level unit with the following error: `Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory.` It is a normal practice to start scripts after installation, but the sudo rights permit me to start my script. Maybe I'm missing something. Someone knows how to overcome this problem?

The command which is use to start script: `systemctl --user start test.service`. When it is executed from installer it actually becomes `sudo systemctl --user start test.service`.(Same doesn't work from terminal).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I have managed to fix the issue. It was not an issue to begin with, just my lack of knowledge about DBus sessions and how do they work. I hope that my answer will help someone.

When you will open terminal and execute `systemctl --user command unit`
everything will be fine, but when you will try to do under `sudo` or switch to another user using `su` command, you will fail with error that I had:

```
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory.
```

The problem is that `systemctl` to connect to user sessions uses dbus session address which is set in `DBUS_SESSION_ADDRESS` env variable.
When you do `sudo` or `su` you get a very limited environment, simply you are missing `DBUS_SESSION_ADDRESS` and other env variables.
So when you get similar errors, check your environment perhaps something important is missing.